# Is "Speedy" really Thea's code name?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In the final episode of the 3rd season when Oliver says "I think I already told everyone to call you Speedy", I thought he was being a wiseass. Yet in the 4th season I've frequently heard him call her that when they've "suited up". Is this really the handle Thea's been going by?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, her codename is really Speedy. In-universe, it's Oliver's old nickname for her, from when they were kids:

> **Oliver:** No one's called me [Ollie] in a while, Speedy.
>
> **Thea:** Worst nickname ever.
>
> **Oliver:** What, always chasing after me as a kid? I thought it fit pretty well.
>
> <sup>*Arrow* Season 1 Episode 1: "Pilot"</sup>

Out of universe, it's a reference to the [legacy *Green Arrow* sidekick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedy_(comics)). Speedy was one of Roy Harper's many aliases; along with "Arsenal" (the one they ended up using on *Arrow*) and the incredibly imaginative "Red Arrow".

Comment: In 3x23 (My Name is Oliver Queen), Thea suggests that they call her Red Arrow, and Oliver says that he told everyone to call her Speedy.

Comment: Oliver also refers to Roy as Speedy. He supposedly does it to constantly remind Roy of Thea so that he doesn't go into a berserker rage.